# Prepared PHP statement not printing out

Tags: php, html, css, variables

I have a statement that is grabbing information from the database, and then is printed out after it is fully prepared.. For some reason though, my script is not printing out the information. I have it in this if statement:

```
if($community == ''){ print $community . "\n\n" . "END" . "\n"; } else { print $community; echo "hi";}
```

This prints out when it is ran:

> > () wrote:

But that is all it prints out. That is coming from the 8th $community .= line. So, my question is, why is it ONLY printing out () Wrote: and not all the variables as well?

```
//  and ticker_symbol ='".$sym."'
    $c_sql = "SELECT message_id, subject, author, FROM_UNIXTIME(datestamp,'%m-%d-%Y') AS formatted_datestamp, forum_id, body, thread, user_id FROM phorum_messages WHERE user_id=13423720 ORDER BY datestamp DESC LIMIT 5";
    $c_result = mysql_query($c_sql,$connection) or die("Couldn't execute get query");

    // Declare Variables
    $body                   = $c_result['body'];
    $forum_id               = $c_result['forum_id'];
    $user_id                = $c_result['user_id'];
    $author                 = $c_result['author'];
    $formatted_datestamp    = $c_result['formatted_datestamp'];

    // Prepare the statement
    if ($c_result != "")  {
        $community .=  $forumPost = '<<<ENDL '. "\n";
        $community .= $body . "\n";
        $community .= 'ENDL;' . "\n";
        $community .= '$forumPost = stripBBCode(strip_tags($forumPost));' . "\n";
        $community .=  "\n";
        $community .= '<div class="comment">' . "\n";
        $community .= '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="reply"><tbody><tr>' . "\n";
        $community .= '<td width="90%"><b><a href="/emerging/forum/read.php?'.$forum_id.','.$user_id.'">'.$author.'</a> ('.$formatted_datestamp.') wrote:</b><br />' . "\n";
        $community .= '<p>'.iconv("ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", "UTF-8", $forumPost).'</p></td>' . "\n";

        $community .= '</tr></tbody></table>'. "\n";
        $community .= '</div>' . "\n";
    }

    // Print out the prepared statement
    if($community = ''){ print $community . "\n\n" . "END" . "\n"; } else { print $community;}
```

Comment: @Diodeus WTF Are you talking about? Quickly removed... I sense a mis-read ;)

Comment: What are you trying to do in $community? It looks like you're building PHP code which won't be run if you just print it?

Comment: I am building a statement that is grabbing it's information from the database @meiamsome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling `if($community = ''){` you only have one equals sign which will set `$community` to a blank string.

I think what you mean to do is `if($community == ''){`

Comment: You've got it twisted on your `$community` string - why do you have exectuable code within it?

Comment: This file use to use Pearl & PHP, but I am simplifying the script to only use PHP.. Do you recommend to not build the statement as a string in $community? @Stanyer

Comment: Definately not - if you want to run PHP code just run the code, you can't execute a string which includes PHP code by simply echoing. You would have to use something such as `eval()` but in your case I don't think that's what you need.

Comment: I took it out of the string and made some modifications to the mysql_query and it worked like a charm. Thank you for the recommendation! I knew that was what I probably was going to have to do, you just reaffirmed the decision.. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

It should have the double-equal:

```
if($community == '')
```

With a single `=` sign you're simply assigning an empty string to variable `$community` - and then checking whether it's `true`.  Empty strings evaluate to `false`, hence you're getting into your `else` part - and losing your value in the process.

Comment: Alright, that returns this: 

() wrote:
hi

Why is it not printing out $community?

Comment: I updated my question reflecting what the issue it if you can take another look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one = sign

you need:

```
if($community == '') { etc...
```